# Excel VBA. Need a macro to randomize permutations (3p3) 3 times without repeating any permutation

Tags: vba, excel

I have 9 cells (which I consider in 3 groups), each group contains the letters A, B and C. Orders are balanced between the 3 groups such that no letter is in the same position twice, e.g.:

A B C   C A B   B A C

I have 3 other cells containing the letters d, e and f. I want to assign d, e and f to A, B and C with the following rules:

1. d, e and f are each reprented once within in each group.
2. d, e and f each combine once with A, B & C

For example :

Ad Be Cf     Ce Af Bd   Bf Ae Cd

Basically I want to write a VBA macro which gives me random assignments of d e f to A B C which follows these rules. I'd like the macro to show me this by putting the cells containing d e f under the cells containing A B C.

Sorry I haven't even tried to write code to do this yet and also sorry if this is a bit of a confusing/poorly formatted question. I'm new to VBA and stackexchange and had a bit of trouble explaining this problem.

Cheers

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8760185/973283.  If it is not, you need to explain why your requirement is different.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding that thread, but I think this is different in that a) I want to randomly generate these permutations, not list them all and b) I only want full permutations of the 3 sets of three that obey the rules I listed, i.e. Ad Be Cf Ce Af Bd Bf Ae Cd is a solution because it has 9 columns

Answer (score 0):

If you have four spaces at the beginning of a line, that line in output in a fixed size font.  This is used for code but also allows you to create images of what you seek.  My best guess is you have something like this:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |  J  |
 --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |     |     |     |  d  |  e  |  f  |     |
 2 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 3 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

From this start position, the code below creates:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |  J  |
 --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |     |     |     |  d  |  e  |  f  |     |
 2 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 3 |  Ad |  Ae |  Af |  Bd |  Be |  Bf |  Cd |  Ce |  Cf |     |
```

My output values are not in the same sequence as yours but that is not in your list of rules.

You say you have three versions of the first set of values, one in each possible sequence.  You do not explain the purpose of the second and third versions so I have not included them.

If this is not what you want, you must offer a fuller explanation of your requirement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Permutate()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long

  Dim ColSrc1First As Long
  Dim ColSrc1Crnt As Long
  Dim ColSrc1Last As Long

  Dim ColSrc2First As Long
  Dim ColSrc2Crnt As Long
  Dim ColSrc2Last As Long

  Dim RowSrc1 As Long
  Dim RowSrc2 As Long
  Dim RowDest As Long

  ' Specify the position of the first set of source values
  RowSrc1 = 1
  ColSrc1First = 1      ' Column A
  ColSrc1Last = 3       ' Column C

  ' Specify the position of the second set of source values
  RowSrc2 = 1
  ColSrc2First = 6      ' Column F
  ColSrc2Last = 8       ' Column H

  ' Specify the start the destination
  RowDest = 3
  ColDestCrnt = 1

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Loop through first set of values and within that loop through
    ' the second set.
    For ColSrc1Crnt = ColSrc1First To ColSrc1Last
      For ColSrc2Crnt = ColSrc2First To ColSrc2Last
        ' Combine one value from the first set with one value in the second set.
        .Cells(RowDest, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
             .Cells(RowSrc1, ColSrc1Crnt).Value & _
             .Cells(RowSrc2, ColSrc2Crnt).Value
        ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
      Next
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Luke  I am pleased if my answer was helpful but I do not understand why.  Your problem is so simple that I would not bother to create a program to solve it.  Is the true problem more complex but you believe you can adapt my code to solve it?