# Macro to insert rows and all possibilities based on a count

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post here but I've visited often in the past for help.

I'm looking for a macro to insert a specific number rows between each entry based the number of items in a collection minus 1,t hen Insert every combination.

I'll do my best to give an example.

Say I have a large number of collections within each collection is a unique item. I want to tie a one-to-one relationship with each item in that collection. So if I have collection `Red` with Items `1`, `2`, and `3` and a collection `Blue` with items `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`.

I have 3 columns in my workbook.

```
Collection, Primary Item, Relationship Item
Row 1 = Red, 1.
Row 2 = Red, 2.
Row 3 = Red, 3.
Row 4 = Blue, A.
Row 5 = Blue, B.
Row 6 = Blue, C.
Row 7 = Blue, D.
Row 8 = Blue, E.
```

My objective is to Insert 2 rows between each row in the `Red` collection, and 4 rows between each row in the `Blue` collection. Then duplicate each collection and target item in the new blank columns as well as each related item in the Relationship item.

This will then read like such:

```
Collection, Target Item, Relationship Item
Row 1 = Red, 1, 2.
Row 2 = Red, 1, 3.
Row 3 = Red, 2, 1.
Row 4 = Red, 2, 3.
Row 5 = Red, 3, 1.
Row 6 = Red 3, 2.
Row 7 = Blue, A, B.
Row 8 = Blue, A, C.
Row 9 = Blue, A, D.
Row 10 = Blue, A, E.
Row 11 = Blue, B, A.
Row 12 = Blue, B, C.
Row 13 = Blue, B, D.
Row 14 = Blue, B, E.
Row 15 = Blue, C, A.
Row 16 = Blue, C, B.
```

and so on.

This will be something that would need to be used multiple times with varying amounts of collections and items within.

I hope I have been descriptive enough and if you have any questions or suggestions on how to simplify my explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you output to a separate worksheet vs. inserting to the existing.
This will keep your parameter file separate for proofing and simplify the looping.

Next you need a nesting looping mechanism to create all the possible combinations. 
Try this link for the loop.
[Creating a list of all possible unique combinations from an array (using VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760185/creating-a-list-of-all-possible-unique-combinations-from-an-array-using-vba)