# Minimum amount of Markets for Maximum Products

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to determine what the fewest <del>amount</del> **number** of markets that render highest <del>amount</del> **number** of unique products.  I'm not sure how to get perform DISTINCT Product Counts with every combination of market.

I can put my data in SQL tables if it's easier with a query.

Here is sample data of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: sample data]

---

Attempting to clarify: Essentially, I'm trying to get all the combination of markets and determine what the distinct count of products are.  From there I can derive percentages.

Example:

```
CHI:          4 DISTINCT PRODUCTS  
CHI/LA:       5 DISTINCT PRODUCTS  
CHI/LA/MIA:   8 DISTINCT PRODUCTS
```

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you're trying to do here. How did you get the market to product mapping shown in your screenshot? Is it totally random? Are there rules? How many products can you have? Find a different way to ask this.

Comment: Rereading it...you're right, I am having a hard time expressing what I'm trying to do.  I think my additions to the bottom will give you a better idea.

Comment: What SQL engine? You would need to loop through the combinations first and then do the count

Comment: @salient Im using SQL Server, I have no idea how to loop, can you help me out? learning...

Answer (score 0):

To count the unique products for a single market it's a scary formula with curly brackets.

I've setup the formula to work on your sheet so try putting it in cell C2 and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array formula when you input it.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($E$2:$E$18<>"", IF($E$2:$E$18=B2, MATCH($F$2:$F$18, $F$2:$F$18, 0))), ROW($F$2:$F$18)-ROW($F$1)+1), 1))
```

You should be able to autofill down to the see the rest of the unique values for the markets you have listed in column B.

Getting the list of markets is complicated but someone asked the question before so check out this answer [Creating a list of all possible unique combinations from an array (using VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760185/creating-a-list-of-all-possible-unique-combinations-from-an-array-using-vba)

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to respond.  The distinct count works great for the individual markets that's the little table I have in bottom right corner, cell H13.