# find all possible combinations vb.net

Tags: vb.net, recursion, statistics, combinations

I have a task where I need to find all possible combinations in a list of numbers which match 
the target number

for example

Target number - 100
Number List 
70
10
90
1
9
4
12
26

The intended result would be

```
70 + 26 + 4
90 + 10
9 + 1 + 90
```

and any others that I have missed

Has anyone done anything like this before or have any ideas on where to start?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you type your question into Google and find a related thread, like, say, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509436/how-to-make-all-possible-sum-combinations-from-array-elements-in-vb) ?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: The general topic you are looking for is called "integer partitions". Also, you can look at your problem as an example of a so-called "zero-one assignment problem", which is a type of "integer programming" problem. Searching for any of the quoted names should turn up a lot of hits.